# Is it appropriate to ask and answer your own question as a method of improving content?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer, canonical

This question was just asked and answered by the same contributor on SO:

[How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

His comment:

> After much searching, I failed to find a canonical Q&A for such a core Java issue. I'm intending this to be the canonical question and will try to close several duplicates to point at this.

My understanding was that the appropriate action in this case should be to clean up an existing question.  There is, in fact, an existing question for this issue:

[How to print object content in correct way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503964/how-to-print-object-content-in-correct-way-with-out-using-tostring-method?noredirect=1)

This question could be edited for clarity, a new answer could be added, or bounties could be awarded to encourage other participants to create better answers.

I question the appropriateness of creating a new question for the purposes of answering it, accepting your answer, and closing other questions to point to it.

Comment: `... with out using toString method` seems irrelevant, and wasn't part of original question. It should probably be removed since it is causing only misunderstanding since `toString` is correct answer to solve this problem.

Comment: @Pshemo Agreed, it even appears to have been [added after the fact](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10503964/revisions) see rev #4. However, it was enough to throw me off the scent when I was out hunting for dupes.

Comment: I would suggest that the question was edited to add that text to make it more searchable.  Indeed, that is exactly how I found it.

Answer (score 10):

I am the author of the question in... question.

In all honesty, if I'd found [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503964/how-to-print-object-content-in-correct-way-with-out-using-tostring-method?noredirect=1), I probably would have chosen to clean it up and post my answer there. But I didn't, because the title at the time of my searching was:

> How to print object content in correct way **with out using toString method**

... so it kinda fell off my radar.

My goal here is to do good, not evil. After seeing countless questions related to this topic, I spent quite some time searching for that classic, highly upvoted, obvious duplicate. I personally failed to find one. Even the one you found, for example,  has just 6 or 7 duplicates pointing at it, so it doesn't even appear to be particularly canonical.

In short: you did well by finding a question that would have been a good starting point for a canonical Q&A. However, I didn't find that in my own search.

So that leads us to the question: what do we do now? I would suggest (although perhaps I'm biased) that we leave my Q&A open and begin to use it as a sink for duplicate questions. But I'm open to other points of view. Again, I'm just trying to make this a better place for novice Java programmers.

Full disclosure: I've already added my question to the [Java tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) (see "Frequently Asked Questions") so we'll have to edit it out of there if we opt to close this and go with something else.

Comment: Your first version of this answer stated that if you had found that question you would have cleaned it up instead of creating a new one.  This is still the appropriate course of action.

Comment: @ErickRobertson Doesn't that just seem like quite a lot of effort now, for little gain? I agree that would have been the better way to start this, had I found the question. But I didn't. So here we are in a situation which isn't really that bad; can't we just make do?

Answer (score 9):

I think it is entirely appropriate, especially for questions that are asked and answered over and over again.

As far as "cleaning up" is concerned, I am against the idea of taking someone else's specific question and the corresponding answers and turning them into general Q&A's.  It is more acceptable if you are turning your answer into a generic one ... but that is a different scenario.

In my opinion, Duncan has done good work that is of benefit to the community and he should be commended.

---

> I question the appropriateness of creating a new question for the purposes of answering it, accepting your answer, and closing other questions to point to it.

If someone else had closed the other questions, would *that* have been appropriate?  If not, you are really getting into the area of peoples' motivations for doing things, and I think that *that* is a dangerous place to go.

Comment: To be fair to Erick, the question he's referring to wouldn't have required significant edits to make it generic. It was pretty generic already. I just didn't find it, due to the rubbish title. I think we all agree this *could* have been done differently. I just think we should stop worrying about it :-).

Comment: Think on this. 1) Erick could have changed the title of the original question himself to make it easier to find and/or more relevant to the question.  2) The gist of the original Q&A (with its title) is different to Duncan's new one.