# In what cases is it acceptable to answer your own question?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, self-answer, instant-self-answer

When asking a question on SO, there is an option to answer your own question immediately (Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style). In what cases it's acceptable to do so? I've just taken advantage of this feature, but it seems that answering your own question is not being well received by the community ?

Comment: Also related [post 1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288909/2982225), [post 2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251874/2982225), [post 3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288329/2982225)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's acceptable when

1. your question is a good, on-topic question that could reasonably be answered by others; and
2. you know the answer to it.

Assuming you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767594/how-to-remove-each-null-character-from-a-text-file) -- your question seems very basic, but I think it meets these criteria. I expect (being so basic) that it is probably a duplicate, so posting your own question with an answer may appear to some as a bad-faith attempt to attract a few upvotes.