# What subjects would be good for a self-answered question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, self-answer, instant-self-answer

I'm good at researching, and I'm also good at debugging, so I rarely find the need to ask for help here. But I still want to contribute questions, which is an enormous part of SO. I have gotten the majority of my rep from answering questions, but I would like to get some variety. Of course the badges and rep will be a bonus.

I read the blog post [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), which brings up the metaphor of the TV show Jeopardy. I feel that it fits in a different way: I have the answers (or can easily find them), but I need to find the questions.

I've already looked through virtually everything on the subject of self-answers, but there's little that explains that about finding the perfect question.

I find a lot about what content we all want to go away (spam, gibberish, help-vamps, great wall of code), but not very much about what content we want to see more of.

I can think of several types of questions that I have considered doing a QA pair with:

- Canonicals. In particular, I see this `cannot get property ____ of null` error floating around for JS. I don't know much JS, so I figure it would be a learning experience.
- Documentations. I don't really like how everything is written, so it might be a good idea to write my own version. Of course I would focus on a particular topic for each post. (I am currently sitting on one of these, but I haven't decided to submit it.)
- Speed tests. Computer science with both computers and science, gathering data and making conclusions. I would pick two valid methods of doing something and compare them. There are a plenty of questions with equally unconvincing answers. (I am able to test Perl, Python, Ruby, Bash and, of course AppleScript programs in Automator, and it shows how long the execution time took.)

---

I know that this is subjective (but this *is* Meta), but I hope it will help people like me develop a good QA pair. (It shouldn't be too broad if you stick to one of the three options I outlined.) And it will benefit the community by giving it more of the content it wants to see.

Which subjects seem good for a self-answer? Can anyone provide some facts from SEDE maybe?

Comment: Why not just do what you know?

Comment: It's pretty hard nowadays for writing good canonical Q&A pairs. Make sure your question is on-topic and well described in 1st place.

Comment: Basically, any topic that you could ask a good question about. Self-answered questions should be judged like any other. If something would be a good question for others to answer, it could be a good question for you to self-answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver The problem of finding a question to go with that answer still remains.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Could you elaborate on that? The way I would go about writing a canon question would be to describe the text of the error and mention what circumstances it occurs under.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to create questions just to get badges.  While it's theoretically possible to create good content when you're just asking questions for the badges/rep, I've yet to see it ever actually happen in practice.

Comment: @Servy: That's a really good point. Hope you don't mind if I quote it in my answer.

Comment: @Servy It's not just for badges/rep. That's just a byproduct of creating something useful.

Comment: @JoshCaswell No, I forbid it!  (Sure go ahead.)

Comment: @Laurel Yet you said, `"But I want to ask questions, because I'd like to get some of the badges."`

Comment: @Servy The presence of badges shows that the community values good questions. When you earn them, it's a symbol that you are contributing a lot of value to the community.

Comment: Sure, but my point stands.  People asking questions just to try to get rep/badges, in my experience, tend to produce low quality content.  It's the people asking questions because they have an interesting question to ask that ask the highest quality content, and simply end up with a badge as a result.  You should avoid just doing things to get badges, and instead simply try to contribute valuable content when you have a valuable contribution, and badges will come without you even considering them.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best example I've seen of a self-answered question: [How can I rearrange views when autorotating with autolayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30515009) I also shamelessly offer my own [Unpacking a struct ending with an ASCIIZ string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11850950) for consideration.

You can look for canonical subjects if you want, but I'd suggest going for long tail stuff instead. Basically, the next time you have a puzzle that you can't immediately find the answer to, keep track of the process of solving it. Turn those notes into a question, and then turn the solution into an answer.

Comment: Do you think that the "long tail stuff" will get closed as too broad? Because that's a major concern I have.

Comment: It shouldn't, if you're asking a specific question. Though I admit, sometimes people have weird allergic reactions to self-answered questions.