# Answering my own question with advice from a deleted comment

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672511/how-to-make-images-of-different-height-and-weight-the-same-using-css-and-percen/48672950?noredirect=1#comment84390134_48672950) yesterday and a user (can't remember who) gave an answer that did not help me, but in the comments gave a completely different answer that did help me find a solution. Now that answer (and the comment) have been deleted. Would it be bad for me to answer my own question based on the users comment?

I don't think this is a duplicate of [What subjects would be good for a self-answered question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322248/what-subjects-would-be-good-for-a-self-answered-question) because I'm not asking if I have a good enough reason to answer the question (since the problem isn't solved in any other answers or comments), I'm asking if it's right for me to basically take credit for another users answer -- (I did find his name so I would credit him, but hopefully you get the point).

Comment: It is kind of interesting in this case though because there is no way to give attribution. That and from what it sounds like the comment didn't actually answer the question but just got you in the direction of the proper solution, I would say that it is not a case where attribution would be necessary, nor even community wiki for that matter. I would post the solution with a proper explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By all means, please do so.

There's no downside - the author gets credit and clearly wasn't going to post an answer anyway.

And the question gets an answer.