# If I have a similar question to one that received poor feedback should I improve it, or ask my own?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I have a question that is basically the same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509029/how-to-convert-fileimageinputstream-to-inputstream-in-java.

However, the question has received poor feedback, and is not a really good question overall.

I also have found an answer to this question (as well as my own), within a few minutes of research.

Should I edit that question to make the question better for everyone, while providing my answer? Or shall make my own question, while providing an answer, and start fresh for everyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go ahead and make a new post. What you linked to isn't even a question and should just be removed.

I assume you already know about self-answering, but just in case not: [What is this "answer your own question" jazz?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)

Please be sure your self-answered question is a decent question in its own right, though: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will do that.  I also appreciate the links on answering own questions.  I've done this before, but it's good to get more info.  As for the question in the OP, it's a legitimate question, but what's being asked in the title, isn't shown in the body lol.