# When answering your own question, do you need to show what you've tried?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

Posted a question and used "Answer your own question" to post an answer instantly with the question.

[How to get the count of day with most rows with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470801/how-to-get-the-count-of-day-with-most-rows-with-mysql)

Because this was a purely educational question, I didn't include what I tried to solve the problem. I just stated the question short and simply.

I got downvoted. I thought the question was clear, and I assume it's because without looking at the answer I posted, it might look like I was being lazy.

I am aware of this question outlining some general guidelines for self-answers, but I don't see much on the usual rule of show what you've tried.

[How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d)

What, if anything, should I have added to the question?

Comment: The question should have enough information on it's own for someone to formulate an answer without looking at existing answers. It's hard for you, as both the asker and answer, to be able to objectively see what would be requierd to answer it without providing the answer in the question. In this case, some table structure may have helped.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted?

Comment: possibly due to a downvote button existing, who knows.

Comment: @Goose As the tooltip says, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: @Servy I mean the meta question. I wasn't sure if I was approaching self-answers correctly, and I'm glad I asked, but I'm getting sarcasm and a rain of downvotes. I feel like I have made people angry or that people think that I am a bad user because of this mistake. This makes me reluctant to get clarification on meta in the future.

Comment: It's also a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d but I don't know if it should be closed as such since it's seeking advice about a specific Q&A.

Comment: Why would you assume that people are angry or that you are a bad user because this question received downvotes? Perhaps that is the fundamental issue...

Comment: @Goose I know you were talking about the meta question.  The same comment applies.  Do you assume that nobody has ever asked what needs to be included in a self answered question, that there is no guidance at all on how to ask one, etc.?

Comment: @CodyGray mean spirited and upvoted sarcasm and no helpful comment on the meta question itself.

Comment: @Goose How is it mean spirited?  Telling you that you can't know why someone choose to downvote you isn't mean spirited, it's being helpful.  Some playful sarcasm was used to lighten the mood.  Sadly, it appeared to not have helped.

Comment: @Servy perhaps I am taking things wrong, if so I'm sorry. Either way, I've been downvoted a lot. Should I close these questions?

Comment: Votes on Meta don't affect your rep. But you've got two positive answers so you can't delete now. I suppose you could flag this as a dupe to the question I linked to above, but accepting one the the answers ought to be sufficient.

Comment: @Goose You could vote to close it, I guess, if there's a close reason you think applies.  If you mean delete it, you can't, because it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @Servy I've just edited both questions and will hope that they are useful to users in the future.

Comment: @Goose there is a standard link for this somewhere, but...  voting on meta works differently -- a downvote *may* mean your question has a quality problem, but *more commonly* it means "I disagree with this." A downvote may simply mean "-1 for suggesting you might not need to" in this case. It's a little ambiguous, but it's meta, it's how it goes.

Comment: I +1ed because I thought it was a good question, but it's covered by duplicates so maybe I might not have done that. Don't care that much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, imagine you are writing the question/answer pair for an unrelated visitor (which you are). The question will still need to provide good context for the purposes of:

- Searching for the question (informative title, error trace, etc.)
- Confirming the user is experiencing the same problem (machine environment, goal you are attempting, wrong attempts that are necessary things to try first)
- Allowing for other answers to pop up (maybe you did it wrong, or maybe a better answer emerges in a year)
- Allowing other users to confirm whether your solution is good or not (vote on it, explain there is a better way)

From experience, I have definitely learned my self-answers were the wrong way to do my problem before.

This fundamental scaffolding still needs to be present.

In practice my self-answered questions tend to be a little thinner. But not by much. The quality question is still about as important as the quality answer.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it has very practical advice to avoid my mistake in the future.

Answer (score 16):

The standards for what makes a good question do not change because you've decided to self-answer. This is just an extension of the general rule that the quality of *answers* do not have any effect on the quality of *questions*. If you post a bad question, but I post a great answer, you'll get a bunch of downvotes and I'll get a shiny reversal badge.

Naturally, you don't have to get carried away with "what have you tried?", but you need to ask the question the same way that you normally would if you didn't know the answer. In this case, although I'm not a database expert, it *seems* like the question would need to contain some kind of commentary about what your database schema looks like in order to properly direct the answers.

Aside from that, if you're going to post a self-answered (canonical?) question, you might consider making it slightly more *general*.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think a question necessarily needs to show "effort" (self-answered or otherwise), but it *does* need to be clear what exactly you're asking *from just the question itself*.

In your case, reading *just the question* it's not at all clear to me what exactly you're asking here.

Remember that while self-answering your own question is both allowed and encouraged *other people need to be able to provide answers as well*. On several occasions when I've self-answered my own question other people provided *better* answers than the one I posted!

Comment: I'm not sure what was unclear about the answer. What sentences would have clarified it?

Comment: @Goose The table layout, sample rows, expected output.