# Posting imperfect answers to your own question

Tags: discussion

Before I post a question on Stack Overflow, I spend quite a bit of time trying to answer it myself. Along the way I've thought up solutions that aren't quite right, maybe because they're solutions to a slightly different problem, or I only have a partial solution, or it's just a plain old hack and I want to know the proper way.

When I post the question I want to include the extra answers. They stop people posting things I already know I don't want (which wastes everyone's time) and maybe they help get to a good answer by letting someone just fill in a detail rather than having to think up the whole thing. Plus, sometimes examples help illustrate a question better than a literal statement. Most of all, they may be useful to others who stumble on my question from Google, even if they weren't useful for me. Just to be clear, these are *not* answers that I would then accept; I still want someone to come in with a better answer.

Unfortunately, a wall of text is a less attractive thing to answer than a one-liner, even if it's easier on reflection e.g. I put a lot of effort into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138482/pyspark-how-do-i-convert-an-array-i-e-list-column-to-vector), but it only got a single vote, which was down!

- What is the right thing to do in this sort of situation?
- Not include my research?
- Carry on as I am?
- Post them as answers (or one big answer) to my own question, even though though they're not actually quite answers?

Edit: Thanks for the responses and to Tiny Giant for the bounty on my question (that would've been my next action once I established whether to edit my question). I'll carry on posting long but structured questions.

Comment: One down-vote is basically _nothing_: only one person decided your question was somehow 'bad', so what? I'd say, that question's really long, and not so many people would read it completely and thus, will be unable to answer. The questions should be concise, but _informative_, to my mind.

Comment: I'm not upset about a downvote. I asked this more because of the lack of attention. I'm guessing that most people look at the wall of text and (understandably) think, "I don't have time to read that!". I want to know if shorter question + several answers would be acceptable to StackOverflow's format, given that they're not *really* (quite) answers, because maybe that would seem a bit less intimidating.

Comment: if these answers are not really answers, they'll get downvoted, that's how the system works.

Comment: I have similar issues. I do not have my own blog and I do like StackOverflow too much. So I post here and on related StackExchange sites long questions with long answers which do not attract many good people at the beginning. Tumbleweed they call it.

Comment: @ForceBru So you think I should indeed post them as answers. Should *I* downvote them, given that I know they're not good answers (for me)?!

Comment: You cannot vote on your own answers.

Comment: @ArthurTacca, I think quite the opposite, actually. You'd better include a short list of what you've tried in your question with explanation why these solutions aren't what you want. BTW, nobody can vote on their own posts.

Comment: I think you ought to write down your research. But maybe mark it as "here is what I ve done so far" or otherwise clearly separate it from the core of your question. If you post your research as (incomplete) answers, it seems to me like "playing" the system, not really using it. I think highlighting your core question while separating but still mentioning your own research might attract more people to answer. in any case, good research provides a great entry point when trying to come up with an answer.

Comment: somewhat tangentially related: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165/839601)

Comment: That question is _very_ far from a "_wall of text_" (everything in one long rambling paragraph). I don't know the subject area, but it looks well-laid out, seems to clearly show what you want to do and what doesn't work or is not ideal. I suspect the lack of answers is more to do with the fact that you've already thought of all the "obvious" answers. Including that you've done that (and why they're not suitable/ideal) can only be to the benefit of any potential answers by not wasting their time. The downside is that it needs someone who can spot a "not obvious" answer that you didn't.

Comment: Just put TLDR version at the top. Long question is not a problem for reader IF there is a chance he can answer it. What reader do not want is reading whole text to realize it's not his area of expertise. TLDR should help with that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just carry on as you are. You'd be surprised how many people would be impressed by a wall-of-text question, especially when it's less of a wall of text and more of a wall of [well-explained and well-illustrated attempts at solving the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725204/how-do-i-get-a-lone-element-in-the-last-line-of-a-flexbox-layout-to-look-the-sam) (in which the explanations describe not only the code itself but why/how the existing attempts are flawed).

Answer (score -14):

Formulate your research as independently answerable Question/Answer pairs, possibly as community wikis, and link them in your actual question as things you tried, explaining why the linked answers don't answer your question.

Comment: Unless they're actually separate questions that can be answered independently, this is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @NathanTuggy it was my impression that they were: "solutions that aren't quite right, maybe because **they're solutions to a slightly different problem**"

Comment: If the asker isn't sure whether they fit or not, nobody will hesitate to dupe-close them.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't follow. What do you mean by fit? They are independently answerable, but related questions and answers, that are used by the OP to help narrow down his question better. If the question can be closed as a dupe, then the OP will have his answer.

Comment: No, I mean the OP is clearly not sure whether they are part of the original question or not, so no one else will hesitate to assume that they *are*, resulting in dupe-closure *of the OP's questions to each other*.

Comment: @NathanTuggy seems like either you are visioning it very differently from me, or that would be a mistake on behalf of the close-voters (and a different problem altogether). I'm thinking of something like, "I tried this (linked question/answer), which doesn't answer my question because the foo doesn't bar..." etc.

Comment: Even if you *do* post them separately, you'd still have to link to every one of the separate Q&As in the master Q&A and convince people not to vote to close it as duplicates of any of those Q&As. How is that any better than just maintaining one single question?

Comment: @BoltClock I think the main difference would be in the size of the new question. Another benefit I can imagine with independent questions, is that perhaps a small change could be made to a linked answer to make it more general, and answer the new question. Then it would become a clear duplicate.