# Bilingual questions

Tags: support

I am thinking of migrating some IT-specific FAQ from a public telegram group into Stack Overflow. The domain area is quite popular: Java, ESB, integration, etc.

Two pitfalls I have:

- All the questions and answers are now in Russian. We all (authors) are going to translate it into English. What is the best way to publish it on Stacko Overflow -- English versions on https://stackoverflow.com and Russian one on https://ru.stackoverflow.com? Is there any special way to link same questions on different languages?
- May I tag origin of this questions with some tag, e.g., #mskxiug (aka Moskow SAP XI User Group)? Or is this wrong practice?

Comment: Please post questions only if you are 100% sure that they are on-topic here. I don't think it will be possible to mark this questions as coming from a specific source. You questions will have to follow the same quality criterias as any other question on SO. And please make sure that you have the proper rights on the original questions to repost them here.

Comment: related: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165/839601)

Answer (score 2):

I personally think that a question on Stack Overflow in English is a good addition to an original one on Stack Overflow in Russian, especially if you know the answer.

Currently there is no "official" way to associate two questions between the sites, but the Russian—speaking community developed a [question association tool](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4857/). The tool works only if you have the same question on both sites. An association is added on Stack Overflow in Russian through a comment and then I with help of others Stack Overflow employees update a site setting on Stack Overflow in English (please take a look at [the post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4857/) for more information).

Please do not use any extra tags. Tags are supposed to structure the knowledge base itself, but not for marking the source from what the questions came from. If you need any kind of technical help with Telegram API, Stack Overflow API or any other stuff related to it, please feel free to [contact me in person](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile) or ask on Meta Stack Overflow in Russian as well as here. I did a bit of research on the topic of integration Stack Overflow and Telegram before which you might find useful. Will be glad to share!