# What's "primarily opinion-based" about the question: "Does this code exhibit a bug?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Granted, that's not the exact wording I used in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46744894/1889329) I asked, but it essentially boils down to this. It's a question that comes up so many times, that I decided to ask, and submit an answer along with it. The answer ends with a clear statement along the lines of: It is a bug under the following conditions.

Within minutes I received a down-vote. I like short and crisp questions. Someone else doesn't. I can live with that.

The down-vote came with a close-vote. Reason: *"primarily opinion-based"*. I'm puzzled. Is that question *really* looking for opinions? If it can be argued that indeed it is, how can it be improved?

---

Original version of the post that received downvotes/close votes:

> There doesn't appear to be a consensus on whether passing `1` as the first argument to [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) is a bug. Is it?

Comment: The user who seems to have close-voted gave you a comment on how the question can be improved. You should also add to the discussion here that you self-answered the question. Part of the problem is that the answer doesn't really fit to the questions.

Comment: @BDL: I was under the impression, that *"I decided to ask, and submit an answer along with it"* would sufficiently explain, that I self-answered the question.

Comment: Although I agree with the idea, like the answer, and don't think it needs closing, it *is* a very poorly *phrased* question. You seem to be asking in order to garner "consensus", which is not really what Stack Overflow is for. If you meant to ask whether it is consistent with the documentation, then you should have asked that directly. I agree with Robert that a small motivating code sample would also improve the question, to provide some context.

Comment: Ok, less short, less crisp. I hope everyone is happy.

Comment: Yes, that's better. I hardly think that qualifies as "verbose" or difficult to read. The title is the part that's supposed to be short and crisp.

Comment: I must mention that I'm not the one downvoting or closing-voting. I don't like the content somewhat, but whether use of `SendInput` is correct is clearly not an "opinion-based" matter.

Comment: This is essentially duplicate of [How to ask self-answered q](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d): questions must meet quality standards and are voted on separately from answer(s). Indeed original versions of the post was asking for discussion and did not show any effort *in the question*.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I beg to differ. The original version didn't ask for discussion, but facts. Plus, the mere presence of the question itself shows research effort: Looking through *numerous* code samples using an API (all showing a common pattern), reading the documentation, and finally condensing that into a question. Just because you do not *see* the effort, doesn't mean that there wasn't any effort. I updated the question, and it doesn't show any more research effort *in the question*, but users were now happily up-voting it, because they could now see a (to them) meaningless MCVE.

Comment: I tried to explain why I believe your edit makes question good quality in the answer... Essentially original version reads as "Bob said XXXX, is it right?" without any context (and there huge number of similarly looking questions that are non-answerable). Edit made it very concrete with sample showing clear case when it can be a problem and you change phrasing from someone else's opinion to your own which reads more conviencing.

Answer (score 10):

I read your question and immediately wondered *why* one would suspect that "passing `1` as the first argument to SendInput" would be a bug. There is some missing context here. If you could include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that would help us understand the context and reasoning behind your question.

Comment: One would suspect that passing `1` as the first argument is a bug, because they are told so. The question itself is strictly relevant to Windows API developers, and there really isn't much more context that needs to be conveyed. Any sort of missing context unfolds in the answer.

Comment: @IInspectable but not all readers of this site are Windows API developers. They may not understand why the question is meaningful and are likely to downvote and close vote if they see it as meaningless.

Comment: Correct. And those developers, that aren't looking for a Q&A pertaining to the Windows API are neither the intended audience, nor would they discover, read, comment, or vote on it. Are you suggesting that it would be helpful, if a domain-specific question would be worded so that it can be understood by everyone? If so, how would you propose to do so?

Comment: @Robert Columbia: Readers who aren't Windows API developers have no business voting to close a question that isn't even intended for them in the first place. Say I know nothing about Haskell. Should I vote to close a question about Haskell just because it's about Haskell and I have no idea what the asker is talking about because I haven't learned the language?

Comment: Who told them and where? The linked documentation doesn't tell that. Why would someone think that passing 1 as an input is a bug? And in my opinion it isn't. The problem is NOT sending 1 as input but with calling SendInput several times to send a sequence of events. If the sequence consists of 4 signals, then calling SendInput twice with 2 as first parameter is also wrong. The questions should be more along the line "How to send atomic input sequences with SendInput?". (And as a side note: There is no indication in the question that you are talking about such sequences of events).

Comment: @BoltClock: That's not the point. I'm familiar with the Windows API and have used SendInput before (also with a 1 as parameter). The question itself without reading the answer doesn't make sense. For self-answered questions the same standards should be applied as for all other questions. Do you think that a expert Windows API programmer could answer that question without context?

Comment: @BDL: Er, I did. Now you may not call me an *"expert Windows API programmer"*, but yes, at least one member of this site could provide an answer. If the question doesn't make sense without reading the answer, then all is well. The truth is in the answer. The question is deliberately short, so as to not waste time. You were told that *in your case* passing `1` is a bug. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46744894/1889329) that explains why.

Comment: @BDL: Robert appears to be arguing that a question is subject to closure just because a reader's domain knowledge prevents them from fully appreciating the question. If the question makes no sense even to a seasoned Windows API programmer, there's a pretty good chance the question is actually bad. If the question does make sense but is simply based on a false premise, an expert could still answer to that effect.

Comment: @BoltClock but a question that is based on a false premise (e.g. "Why are strings mutable in Java?" or "Why does dereferencing a null pointer in C always return zero?") would be worth a downvote even if it is answerable and not closeable.

Comment: @Robert Columbia: I think IInspectable is less interested in the downvote ("I can live with that.") and more in the close vote.

Comment: @BoltClock I wasn't the one who closevoted. I'll let them come forward if they are willing to to explain their reasoning.

Comment: Nevertheless, you do point out an unfortunate reality that folks who aren't in the target audience of a question in the first place think it's unclear just because they lack the domain knowledge or expertise to understand it and vote to close accordingly.

Comment: @BDL: I'm interested, though, what context you seem to be missing. Even without reading the answer, assuming sufficient domain-specific knowledge, wouldn't you arrive at exactly at the same answer? I'm also not sure what *doesn't* make sense about the question. There are only 3 cases to consider: A single call, a sequence of calls where the input need not be atomic, and a sequence of calls where the input must be atomic. All of this can be extracted from the question as asked.

Comment: @IInspectable I think what robert is getting at is that they don't see what sequence of events led you to believe that it would be a bug. (I have no experience in the target domain so bear with me), what did you expect to happen that didn't, and what happened instead? (this can be phrased as if you didn't know the answer before asking the question). (Possibly along the lines of "Why does passing 1 to SendInput cause X to happen instead of Y?" in which case the answer would still fit, with some minor modification).

Comment: @TinyGiant: Even if I could agree with that, it's not at all related to the question I asked: Can the question conceivably be interpreted as *"primarily opinion-based*"?

Comment: @IInspectable I understand that, and completely disagree with it being closed as primarily opinion based. _However_, when you post a question like this on meta, meta regulars might read between the lines and see the question "How can I improve this question?" which is a much more generally useful question. I can understand where Robert is coming from, and it seems like good advice. If you want to do some handwaving and ignore the advice given or say that the advice is not applicable to the question asked here, then I don't have anything else to say to you.

Comment: @IInspectable: Well, taken to the extreme, anything can and will be interpreted as anything by at least one person. Sorta like the dead horse of users taking friendly constructive criticism personally, and people perceiving outright *offense* in otherwise harmless content.

Answer (score 3):

[Original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46744894/1) of *the question* was way opinion based, broad and lacking any demonstrated research hence deserve downvotes<sup>*</sup> and close votes (see [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d)).

What ideally should have happened: someone with reasonable understanding of the problem realized that this is indeed a good question without existing duplicate answer and edit the question in shape (i.e. by adding sample and cleaning language to remove what essentially asking for discussion).

Harsh reality is that in many cases such an edit would be reverted by OP with comment "keep your @#$@ hands away from my post, you @##$#". As result downvoting without comment is only safe option. Even leaving comment without downvote risks revenge downvotes as such question likely to get downvotes anyway.

---

In this particular case OP took the next best approach with the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46744894/2) of *the question* making it clear and specific enough to be considered good on-topic question. OP also turned text of the post that was more like "someone said XXXX" into "I believe XXXX is true because YYYY" which is much easier to answer specifically.

Other option could be to bring question up to meta first to see if it is indeed new and how to ask properly. I'd limit that option to questions intended to be canonical answers similar to "What is NRE/NPE" questions.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>I would have downvoted even my own self-answered question -
 [What question mark means in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075113/what-question-mark-means-in-c-sharp-code)... And I have no idea how to make that one better. In that particular case I don't care as I created it only to serve as search/duplicate target - but still had to bring it up to Meta for help.</sub>

Comment: There is ***nothing*** even remotely opinion-based about a question asking whether a particular use of an API is correct.

Comment: @IInspectable original version clearly :) was about coding style - whether you should pass 1 as constant or as size of the passed in array. :)

Comment: I can be equally clearly assumed, that following the documented contract is a given, so 1 *is* the length of the array. Although I probably could (and should) have written *"passing a single-element array"* instead.