# Why does milliseconds in a VBA Date variable trigger angry responses?

Tags: discussion

I posted a technical question that I was surprised drew angry responses.
Sure, I want to be right, but there is more I need to learn and the discourse has been stifled by the anger, and the angry moderator's deletion power.

[Milliseconds in VBA Date variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987692/does-this-code-prove-excel-vba-date-variables-can-store-milliseconds-with-no-pro)

Lots of my comments were deleted.

I'd like to post another question, like Does anybody know if there is really a difference between VB and VBA Date data type?  But it seems like a hot button for these moderators.  And I think the angry moderators will just mark it as duplicate anyway.  What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Likely due to what seems to be stretching a data type beyond it's intended purpose.  Yes, it *can* be done.  But it generally should *not*, if you like maintainable code.

Comment: No one is going to get angry with you over a question topic. Are you sure it wasn't something else?

Comment: Only 2 comments of yours, on one of the answers, were deleted. One was deleted by a moderator after it was flagged, you deleted the other comment. That's really not a lot.

Comment: I think this is anger:  You must really hate your fellow programmers and yourself to violate the encapsulation of data types like that. – this 2

Comment: Moreover, only *5 comments of yours* were deleted, ever, 3 by you, and 2 by moderators (the other because it was deemed obsolete). Note that by *moderators* I'm talking about *elected community moderators* like me (note the ♦ diamond next to my name). Everybody else are just community members like you (with perhaps a few more [privileges earned through participation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/). Don't confuse the two groups.

Comment: Last but not least, our community is *expected* to curate content, which includes voting and closing as duplicates or as off topic, where necessary. Emotions have very little to do with those actions. Don't read anything more into those than just *people doing their best to use the site as it was designed*.

Comment: Thank you @fbueckert I want to go RIGHT THERE, but without anger!  Just because SOME FUNCTIONS limit the range of the Date variable type, it DOES NOT MEAN I am stretching a data type beyond it's intended purpose.  Is it the caps that are triggers?

Comment: @BSMP [It takes some looking around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987692/does-this-code-prove-excel-vba-date-variables-can-store-milliseconds-with-no-pro#comment96761780_54991999) (if that's the one you are talking about)

Comment: The all caps does come across as shouting. If you just want emphasis, consider **bold text** but use that sparingly. @AndréKool Yep, I had to expand the comments to see it.

Comment: Side note, it is better to use *italics* **and bold** to emphasize things you are typing as ALL CAPS IS SHOUTY AND ANGRY AND FOLKS TAKE IT NEGATIVELY.

Comment: @Jay: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting), using only capitals is read as shouting very loud and angrily. I see you are also using `[link]` a lot, but we use [markdown formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) here, where we have specific support for marking up text as **bold** or *italics*. There is a 'help' link next to the comment box with a quick overview of the most-used formatting options.

Comment: That statement is more rude than it needs to be, for sure.  But the premise behind it is pretty sound; clever code, isn't.  Remember that you won't be around to maintain this forever; whoever has to take over is going to have a hard time understanding what you're trying to do.  Is it worth the extra headache for someone else to understand what you're doing here, as opposed to using data types for their intended purpose, and just rolling your own for extra functionality?

Comment: @fbueckert I hate to point out that you have bought into his assertion which is *patently false*.  It's like a virus!  You are even elaborating without pausing to recognize it is false!  Almost like you are now invested in it! *Please* let me offer some proof?  Or should I give up now?

Comment: No, I think at this point you're too invested in this for it to be worthwhile to continue.  I'm just going to step out of this entirely, as I don't think there's going to be any good outcome to continuing.

Comment: Look away quickly before the facts appear! Interesting difference between VBA description of the Data data type and VB description: [link]docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/… [link]docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/… The VB version promises ALL the resolution of the IEEE754: "and times from 12:00:00 AM (midnight) through 11:59:59.9999999 PM. Each increment represents 100 nanoseconds" The VBA version omits any mention of sub-second resolution (dumbed down?) but DOES reference the same "IEEE 64-bit (8-byte)".

Comment: The things I think it makes sense to explain are twofold: 1) moderation isn't angry. Moderation is just moderation. Now the comment is definitely not okay, so you should have flagged it. But.... 2) no matter how wrong or rude someone else is, this **never** excuses you from the 'be nice' guideline. Ever. And the be nice also talks about stuff like assuming good intentions. That's super important, as it's easy to read too much emotions in a comment on the interwebs.

Comment: This is even exceeding my attention span soon!  I really invite review, am I ever not nice in my assertions or replies?  I *am* adding stuff up by user1: the pattern of deletions, the dismissal with incorrect arguments, and the recruiting of a confederate (user2 cites user1 as authority in his argument) but I can only appeal to user1 to help?  Seems unlikely but thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: @Jay: "*am I ever not nice in my assertions or replies?*" Well, in this very thread, you SHOUTED at people, which is often reasonably interpreted as anger. "*the pattern of deletions*" One moderator deleted a comment; you deleted another. There is no pattern. Please do not repeat this misinformation about deletion again.

Comment: @Jay: "*I really invite review*" I see little evidence of this in this thread. For example, you say "the dismissal with incorrect arguments". But I see no evidence of "incorrect arguments" here. I see people challenging your assertion that the statements you're talking about are "angry", and I think those challenges are not "incorrect". Indeed, I would say that you have exhibited more anger than anyone else thus far, and it's very difficult to see your position as "inviting review" when you don't even seem to consider the possibility that you are wrong.

Comment: SO users care a lot about the technical accuracy of info presented at the site.  They know what a Date looks like, they have no idea what you look like.  Your desire to be right is pretty fundamentally in conflict with the site's goals, the stronger you assert it the more responses you invite.  [Duty calls](https://xkcd.com/386/).  Don't do it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for your comment.  Can I ask if moderators (the diamond folks) just delete mechanically based on community members with privileges, or do they do significant review?

Comment: @Jay yes, indeed you can ask that (as separate question on this site). I'd strongly recommend reading some existing posts on subject of "why this @#$#$ deleted my comment/question/answer" so before posting that question. The moderators provided plenty of information on how they handle flags on posts and comments already - if you just ask question without *showing* that you've read previous discussions you'll have more of "you @#$@ just don't like me" experience which we really don't like you to have.

Comment: I regret my use of caps, I will do better in the future.  Is there shorthand for "community members with privileges?"

Comment: @Jay: we are human beings, not automatons. If all we did was just delete because something is flagged, why have human moderators at all? So yes, we do review ourselves. Note that not all flags are handled by the moderators; certain flag types are handled by the community through review queues (through voting mechanisms), but may eventually be handled by a moderator if left long enough, and some are handled automatically if enough flags accumulate (e.g. 6 spam flags automatically trigger post deletion).

Answer (score 16):

The post you've linked to is not *a question*. It is some sort of blog entry combining ranting and sample code.

Proper moderation actions on the post in such case are:

- close as "unclear what you are asking"
- possibly downvote if ranting can't be edited out
- possibly comment explaining that question should contain question.

Desired response from author of the post:

- split post into true question and answer parts (make sure to read [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d))
- alternatively delete post from SO and post it to own blog/site/whatever

If you have code that works correctly but you are interested in feedback on your code consider CodeReview (also make sure to check they [guide for SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) ).

Comment: Maybe I should say "This Looks Like Proof to me, am I missing something?"  Would that be a question (with the code)?

Comment: @Jay if that what you wanted to ask... then yes (and it even aligns with the answer provided there). Also open-ended critique of working code is not exactly on-topic on SO and such question could be "too broad"... Side note: based on your comments it is not clear if you *actually* had a question or was open to possibility that doing what you wanted is not a good idea. Asking good question on SO when all you have is an answer is *very hard* (by design) - I'd strongly recommend to read link to self-answer guidance in my answer...

Comment: I am absolutely sincere in trying to find if there is a compelling reason I should not use sub-second time, as it appears to work in that code.  No one posted code showing when it does NOT work, only worry and speculation.  And some vitriol.

Comment: @Jay: I've never used the API or languages you're using, but I found the answer you're having issues with to be sufficiently "compelling", regardless of whether you can create code where it "appears to work". Indeed, I always find "appears to work" to be a generally poor reason for doing something unless I have no other choice. Even moreso if there are a bunch of functions that say that they don't allow it. As such, it's hard to know what would constitute a "compelling reason" for you.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Did you read this link from Microsoft where they explain how to avoid the rounding?  If somewhere Microsoft said "milliseconds are deprecated" they would have won long ago.  This is compelling to me.  [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/875526/milliseconds-are-rounded-to-the-nearest-second-when-you-try-to-assign)  That link says the opposite to me: milliseconds are *supported*, but you have to know a secret..

Comment: @Jay: "*This is compelling to me.*" Then your question is *opinion based*. That is, an answer's validity is based entirely on your opinion of what counts as "compelling". I prefer bullet-proof code, where you write code so that it cannot be broken by someone who doesn't "know a secret". This is especially important when such breakage will be difficult to detect and hard to track down. But that's *me* and how I look at things. We don't want opinion-based questions for this exact reason: they create discussions, acrimony from those whose opinions aren't validated by others, and so forth.

Comment: @NicolBolas When they *infer* that milliseconds are unsupported because some functions state they do not support milliseconds, what is that?

Answer (score 8):

Two things to clarify:

- The users in the context of this discussion **are not diamond moderators**.  Calling them moderators means you're implying that they're diamond moderators, which ain't true - do bear in mind that every user with sufficient rep can moderate content by up or downvoting on it.
- If your question *truly* is a dupe, then the most appropriate action for it would be to close it as a dupe.  Being upset about this fact isn't constructive.

To the comments - they're neither constructive nor helpful.  Saying that you must "hate your fellow programmers and yourself" is inflammatory, even if the message that was *trying* to be conveyed was more innocuous.  Flag a moderator to clean those up since they don't need to be here.

Comment: Thanks, is there a shorthand for "community member with privileges"?

Comment: @Jay: Everyone eventually gets the privilege to down vote, so no, not really.

Comment: I guess.... 'user '? It mostly covers it

Comment: I mean a user who can mark a post "duplicate" and edit your question and delete peoples comments?

Comment: @Jay: Yeah, those are still users. Everyone gets that privilege with reputation.

Comment: @Makoto: Only diamond moderators can delete comments.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I thought that if enough users mark a comment as "unfriendly" or "harassing", then the comment can be automatically deleted.

Comment: Yes, a preponderance of flags from regular community members can cause a comment to be deleted. Also, there are regexes they allow a single flag to delete a comment if its contents match a particular pattern (e.g., “+1 thanks”). @hov

Comment: I am forming the impression that some users treat Stack Overflow like a video game, and gang up on perfectly respectable answers and downvote them "because they can."  Are diamond moderators wise to this and responsive when they see it?

Comment: @Jay: Wise to what? I have only very rarely seen an SO answer get significantly downvoted when there was *nothing* wrong with it. In pretty much every case I can recall, an answer that received downvotes had something that was at least arguably wrong with it. Furthermore, we generally don't police votes; as long as you're voting for the content rather than the user, it isn't anyone's business.

Comment: I cannot help but notice that the attentive non-moderators with privileges quickly deleted my non-inflammatory posts they regarded as unhelpful, but left in place the inflammatory ones that were against my point.

Comment: @Jay: Since this question starts with a statement about comment deletion that is patently untrue, as verified by a diamond moderator who can see which comments were deleted and why, it is difficult to take your statement at face value.

Comment: I regret if I unintentionally disrespected anyone by not knowing the difference between (diamond)moderators, and "community members with privileges".

Comment: @Jay: That wasn't the issue I was referring to. You claimed "*Lots of my comments were deleted,*" when in fact only two comments were deleted, one of which was deleted *by yourself*. One comment is not "lots"; therefore, you significantly exaggerated the number of comments of yours that were deleted. As you can imagine, if someone has already been caught exaggerating the number of deleted comments, that damages the credibility of any future statements about deleted comments.

Comment: I regret that I used the word "many" when I was accidentally including supportive comments by others, my comments on the previous post that led to this post, and edits to the question performed by non-moderator member with privileges.