# Asking a question and publishing my workaround as my own answer

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I've had a problem with python crashing on windows 10 with some simple calls. I've been working for a solution or workaround.

[Python on PyCharm crashes with 'Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003175/)

I've posted my question and published my [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57003176/2) as an answer. I've since then found a better solution.

I've been downvoted for the first [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57003176/2) because someone claimed posting my own workaround is confusing and should have been part of the question.

What is the preferred method of posting a question where the person asking it has already has found a workaround?

I'm aware there has been posted a simliar [question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d). But it doens't consider the matter where your own answer is just a *workaround*.

Comment: @yivi the topic is very similar - I still wonder if this is still the same if the answer is **only** a **workaround**.

Comment: @madmike. It doesn't matter if an answer is a self answer or not, the same quality rules apply.   The premise is: a question has been asked,  and an answer provided.  Is that answer useful to future readers?

Comment: Just hold both your question and your answer to the usual question/answer standards. If you weren't self-answering, would you ask the question like that? If it were someone else's question, would you answer it that way?