# Add header to self-answered Q&A?

Tags: discussion

I was looking around for something simple today; some command to get the version number of `ssh`. I couldn't find anything online and came up with some `sed` command that did the trick.

Then I thought it would be nice to create a [self-answered Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) for other people looking for this same question: [How to get bash ssh version number only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370732/bash-get-ssh-version-number-only)

When I first created the question; I didn't add a header that this was a self-answered Q&A and quickly got a few downvotes (don't really know why though).

Adding a header that this was a self-answered Q&A seemed to make the question at once more acceptable.

So I am left with a few questions:

- was it a bad idea in the first place to create a self-answered Q&A for a simple `sed` command to get the ssh version number? Is this a bad question?
- I don't think there should be different "acceptance criteria" for normal questions and self-answered Q&A, but somehow the header I added seemed to please people; should Stack Overflow add a default header when creating a self-answered Q&A?

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314165)

Comment: You can use the [answer your own question checkbox list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKxJt.png). Or if you haven't found the solution yet, you could post it as a normal question which include research effort and mcve. Then later add your own solution, once you found it.

Comment: Nice Q/A!, it's a pity that many community users think all questions needs code (attempt), instead the best Q/A we have on SO are actually just simply "How can I do this" (scoped sufficiently narrow)

Answer (score 4):

It really shouldn't matter who answers a question. The answer is either a good answer to a well written and well researched question, or it isn't.

Self answering by asking a high quality question and providing a high quality answer is something to be encouraged and applauded but it's not easy to do. You still need to do everything you normally would before asking a new question i.e. find out whether that question already exists, in which case you can add your answer there if it does not have an existing answer that would cover everything you're planning to say.

Adding a header is superfluous should be removed, it does not add anything to the question or the answer. If you want to see whether a question is self answered you can compare the user id of the person who asked the question with the user id of the answer.

Comment: I think my question really is a dupe of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d.
I think I attracted downvotes because my question didn't show my research effort and then got a snowball effect. I was just really asking myself if I was asking the wrong kind of question...

Comment: Re *"It really shouldn't matter who answers a question"*: No, it shouldn't at all, but reputation points envy probably plays a role.