# How should I handle a non reproducible question as a question author?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72833500/16217248) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ob6F.png)) because my app was exiting immediately whenever I launched my app from the Dock but not when I tested it in Xcode. The only change I thought I had made that I thought was significant enough to matter was that my app was done using pure programming rather than any XIB or Storyboard files. But it turns out that an unrelated code fragment in the `main()` function which would `exit()` if some `open()` operation failed was the culprit.

I asked about it and provided a 'minimal' <s>reproducible</s> example, but as it turns out, the problem was not in the example I provided but in an unrelated part of the code I thought was unimportant to the question but was actually the problem. So of course the issue cannot be reproduced using the info in the question so I deleted it. It got an answer that addresses some possible (incorrect) reasons why the problem might be occurring.

Would it be acceptable to edit the question to be about the real problem, like why the `open()` was not working when the app was running from the Dock, even though the new one would be of little resemblance to the old one? What should I do about the fact that it has an answer? Or am I better off leaving it deleted and asking a new question if I see enough value in doing so?

Comment: Ask a new question, and submit the answer to the question at the time of submission, restoring a 1.5 year old deleted question with an inaccurate answer doesn’t seem helpful to the community

Comment: Why do you want to handle this at all? The only downside to you is that the question may *slightly* weight in towards a question ban, but you shouldn’t even be near that. Just move on.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Why do people bother to ask on meta at all... because they want to do the right thing, but what is the right thing to do is frequently vague at best. Asking on meta rather than making a guess is always a good idea.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have a general preference to edit questions into shape as opposed to deleting them if possible. There may be some value in a question about a 'heisenbug' where an app behavior is different depending on how its launched which logically makes no sense. But I am not sure if trying to save this question would be appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general recommendation is to fix question if you actually can produce an MRE.

In this specific case I think deletion is reasonable approach and does not need to be reverted:

- question itself was not related to problem
- editing would invalidate existing (also presumably unrelated) answer which is discouraged
- author of the question is very unlikely to get anywhere close to the question ban hence usual "deleting a question with answer *presumably* has heavy impact toward the ban" guidance can be ignored assuming this is rare/one-time deletion.

You may indeed post a new self-answered question if you feel the information you have is still useful (1.5 years is long time...) and you can actually write a good *question*. Before doing so please review [How do I ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-do-i-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting)